# React-Native Camera error - No suitable URL request handler found for assets-library

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, react-native-camera

I am creating react-native app which allows me to take a picture using camera and upload to AWS S3.

I am able to click the picture and save image to my iPhone camera roll. But, when I try to upload the image, I get error `No suitable URL request handler found for assets-library://asset` as shown below:
[image: iOS image upload error]
Here is the code snippet:

```
import Camera  from 'react-native-camera';    
import {RNS3} from "react-native-aws3";

    class NCamera extends React.Component {
        takePicture() {
            this.camera.capture()
                .then((data) => {
                    const file = { uri: data.path, name: 'image.png', type: 'image/png',}
                    const options = {
                        keyPrefix: "images/",
                        bucket: "my-bucket-name",
                        region: "us-east-1",
                        accessKey: "key",
                        secretKey: "secret-key",
                        successActionStatus: 201
                    }
                    RNS3.put(file, options)
                        .then(response => {
                            if (response.status != 201 )
                                console.log('Error uploading file to S3');
                            else
                                console.log(response.body);
                    })
                        .catch (error => console.log(`Error uploading: ${error}`));
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <Camera
                    ref={(cam) => {
                        this.camera = cam;
                    }}
                    style={styles.preview}
                    aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}>
                    <Text style={styles.capture} onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}>[CAPTURE]</Text>
                </Camera>
            );
        }
    }
```

***Solution***
I added `libRCTCameraRoll.a` which resolved the issue.

Here are the steps:
1. Open `RCTCameraRoll.xcodeproj` in xcode. The file can be found under `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/CameraRoll`
2. Under Build Phases, add `libRCTCameraRoll.a`(screenshot below).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If this is on IOS, I think you need to link libRCTCamera.a in XCode so that the file url can be resolved properly. See [this medium article](https://medium.com/@knowbody/react-native-image-upload-to-s3-bucket-5220941bfea2) for more details on that.

Comment: Adding `libRCTCameraRoll.a` fixed the issue. I updated my post with the solution. Thanks for the link. It helped me resolve issue.